# Выравнивание HTML CSS

Tags: css

Как сделать так, чтобы поля ввода с текстом выравнивались как на фото? Заранее спасибо

```css
.fa-times {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#modal_ad {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #080808;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

form {
  margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
}

#modal_ad form div {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#modal_ad form div input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: none;
}

#modal_ad form div textarea {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  outline: none;
}

#modal_ad form button {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ffc500;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-container">
  <div id="modal_ad">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    <form action="mail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <legend>Если вы знаете об интересном событии, сообщите нам!</legend>
      <div>
        <label for="city">Город</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Например, Сочи">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="name">Событие</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Например, Фестиваль мёда">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="date">Дата, время</label>
        <input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Например, 15-20 января 2019г. с 10:00 до 22:30">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="site">Оф. сайт</label>
        <input type="text" id="site" name="site" placeholder="Например, flating.info (не обязательно)">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="social">Страница в соц. сети</label>
        <input type="text" id="social" name="social" placeholder="Например, vk.com/raiszzz1 (Любая соц. сеть)">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="user_name">Ваше имя</label>
        <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" placeholder="Например, Дмитрий">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="user_phone">Ваш телефон</label>
        <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_phone" placeholder="Например, 8 999 100 10 10">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="user">Кто Вы</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Например, Организатор">
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я использовал **флексы** надеюсь вы не против этого..

```css
.fa-times{
 padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
 text-align: right;
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-container{
 width: 150%;
 
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1000;
}
#modal_ad{
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 2px solid #080808;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 width: 70%;
 font-size: 16px;
}
form {
 margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
}
#modal_ad form div{
 padding-top: 10px;
  display:flex;
}
#modal_ad form div input{
 height: 30px;
 width: 60%;
 margin-left:30px;
  margin-right:20px;
 outline: none;
}
#modal_ad form div textarea{
 width: 70%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 70px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 outline: none;
}
#modal_ad form button{
 width: 30%;
 height: 50px;
 border: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
  margin-top:20px;
  border-radius:20px;
}
label {
  margin-left:auto;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-container">
  <div id="modal_ad">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    <form action="mail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <legend>Если вы знаете об интересном событии, сообщите нам!</legend>
      <div>
        <label for="city">Город</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Например, Сочи">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="name">Событие</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Например, Фестиваль мёда">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="date">Дата, время</label>
        <input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Например, 15-20 января 2019г. с 10:00 до 22:30">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="site">Оф. сайт</label>
        <input type="text" id="site" name="site" placeholder="Например, flating.info (не обязательно)">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="social">Страница в соц. сети</label>
        <input type="text" id="social" name="social" placeholder="Например, vk.com/raiszzz1 (Любая соц. сеть)">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="user_name">Ваше имя</label>
        <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" placeholder="Например, Дмитрий">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="user_phone">Ваш телефон</label>
        <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_phone" placeholder="Например, 8 999 100 10 10">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="user">Кто Вы</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Например, Организатор">
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Название поля и само поле должны стоять близко друг к другу

Comment: @ПавелРумянцев изменил пожете посмотреть

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо было добавить:

- фиксированную ширину лейбла `width: 180px;`
- сделать элемент блочно-строчным `display: inline-block;`
- выравнять текст по какому-либо из краев `text-align: left;`

```css
legend {
    text-align: center;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 180px;
}
.fa-times{
 padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
 text-align: right;
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-container{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1000;
}
#modal_ad{
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 2px solid #080808;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 font-weight: bold;
 width: 70%;
 font-size: 16px;
}
form {
 margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
}
#modal_ad form div{
 padding-top: 10px;
}
#modal_ad form div input{
 height: 30px;
 width: 70%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 outline: none;
}
#modal_ad form div textarea{
 width: 70%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 70px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 outline: none;
}
#modal_ad form button{
 width: 30%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #ffc500;
 border: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-container">
  <div id="modal_ad">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    <form action="mail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <legend>Если вы знаете об интересном событии, сообщите нам!</legend>
      <div>
        <label for="city">Город</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Например, Сочи">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="name">Событие</label>
        <input style="padding-left: 15px;" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Например, Фестиваль мёда">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="date">Дата, время</label>
        <input style="padding-left: 15px;" type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Например, 15-20 января 2019г. с 10:00 до 22:30">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="site">Оф. сайт</label>
        <input style="padding-left: 15px;" type="text" id="site" name="site" placeholder="Например, flating.info (не обязательно)">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="social">Страница в соц. сети</label>
        <input style="padding-left: 15px;" type="text" id="social" name="social" placeholder="Например, vk.com/raiszzz1 (Любая соц. сеть)">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="user_name">Ваше имя</label>
        <input style="padding-left: 15px;" type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" placeholder="Например, Дмитрий">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="user_phone">Ваш телефон</label>
        <input style="padding-left: 15px;" type="text" id="user_name" name="user_phone" placeholder="Например, 8 999 100 10 10">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="user">Кто Вы</label>
        <input style="padding-left: 15px;" type="text" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Например, Организатор">
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для `input` задайте фиксированную ширину, к примеру: `width: 250px`.
И для блока `<div>`, в котором содержится текст и поле ввода задайте свойство `text-align: right;`

Comment: Помогло, спасибо, только я теперь не могу понять как выровнять все по центру?

Comment: задайте форме максимальную ширину max-width и добавьте свойство margin: 0 auto

Answer (score 2):

```css
.fa-times{
 padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
 text-align: right;
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-container{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1000;
}
#modal_ad{
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 2px solid #080808;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 width: 70%;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
form {
 margin: 50px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#modal_ad form div{
 padding-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
#modal_ad form div input{
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height: 30px;
    width: 250px;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#modal_ad form div textarea{
 width: 70%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 70px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 outline: none;
}
#modal_ad form button{
 width: 30%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #ffc500;
 border: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

label {
align-self: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="modal-container">
        <div id="modal_ad">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
          <form action="mail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <legend>Если вы знаете об интересном событии, сообщите нам!</legend>
            <div>
              <label for="city">Город</label>
              <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Например, Сочи">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="name">Событие</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Например, Фестиваль мёда">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="date">Дата, время</label>
              <input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Например, 15-20 января 2019г. с 10:00 до 22:30">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="site">Оф. сайт</label>
              <input type="text" id="site" name="site" placeholder="Например, flating.info (не обязательно)">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="social">Страница в соц. сети</label>
              <input type="text" id="social" name="social" placeholder="Например, vk.com/raiszzz1 (Любая соц. сеть)">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="user_name">Ваше имя</label>
              <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" placeholder="Например, Дмитрий">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="user_phone">Ваш телефон</label>
              <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_phone" placeholder="Например, 8 999 100 10 10">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="user">Кто Вы</label>
              <input type="text" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Например, Организатор">
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Как-то так с флексом.
Некоторые мелочи думаю не составит труда доработать.

П.С. При прсомтре нажать на всю страницу.